# Chrome white page after scrolling

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Google Chrome in Ubuntu 16.04 with two screens and I don't have any graphic card.

I don't understand why while I scroll down through the mouse wheel, sometimes the page becomes white and I have to reload it. Sometimes it becomes white for some ms and become normal again.

Comment: This seems to be a [somewhat common problem](http://superuser.com/questions/440416/chrome-displays-a-page-for-split-second-then-it-goes-blank) - there doesn't seem to be a definitive fix though. Try disabling extensions.

Comment: **Seems** that disabling Adblock solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Up to now, the problem seem solved by disabling Adblock (leaving Adblockplus).

**EDIT:**

The problem unfortunately still persists.

Comment: You shouldn't use two adblockers at the same time anyway - it reduces performance and there's no benefit to doing so.